# How to avoid `ls .` when `find | xargs ls` has no result?

Tags: bash, find, ls, xargs

```
me@new840:~/.config$ ls -al 
total 196
drwx------ 40 me me 4096 Aug 22 22:08  .
drwxr-xr-x 52 me me 4096 Aug 22 12:12  ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4096 Jul 23 04:36  autostart
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4096 Jul 25 00:30  bcompare
drwx------ 20 me me 4096 Aug 22 22:37  Code
drwx------  2 me me 4096 Aug 22 22:50  dconf
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 Aug 15 07:19  deadbeef
-rw-------  1 me me 1131 Nov 21  2016  dleyna-server-service.conf

me@new840:~/.config$ find /home/me/.config ! -user "me" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Al
total 188
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4096 Jul 23 04:36  autostart
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4096 Jul 25 00:30  bcompare
drwx------ 20 me me 4096 Aug 22 22:37  Code
drwx------  2 me me 4096 Aug 22 22:56  dconf
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 Aug 15 07:19  deadbeef
-rw-------  1 me me 1131 Nov 21  2016  dleyna-server-service.conf
```

Actually,the result of `find /home/me/.config ! -user "me" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Al` should be `empty`.

How to avoid `ls .` when `find | xargs ls` has no result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `xargs` has the `-r` option to avoid doing anything if it receives no input, but this is not portable.

With `find`, the solution is simple: use `-exec` instead of `xargs`.

```sh
find /home/me/.config ! -user "me" -type f -exec ls -Al {} +
```

Tangentially, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

Xargs supports the options `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty`. Then the `ls` command is not run when nothing is found.

Note that `find` supports the option `-ls`. Depending on what you want to see, you can skip `xargs` entirely.

Note: Assuming GNU environment.